# Reflow soldering with temperature-sensitive components and without a reflow oven

Tags: soldering, pcb-assembly, overheat

I need to assemble and test a rather large (40x30 cm) board with single sided SMD parts, Sn Ag Cu solder (officially 217°C melting point). Usually I place group after group of components and locally solder these groups with a "hot air pen" (rework solder station), which works beautifully.

However, this method does have problems when parts are tall and contain a lot of temperature sensitive material like plastic connectors or electrolyte caps. For those parts, the hot air can heat the parts way higher than the 260 °C they are usually rated for, before the solder starts to melt, leading to damaged components.

Is there a reliable way to solder such parts when a proper reflow oven is not available ? In particular, I have a plastic multirow SMD connector with a BGA like landing pattern ([Samtec SEARAY](https://suddendocs.samtec.com/literature/searay_soldering1.pdf)) that I don't know how to solder well.

I do have the following:

- hot plate up to 300°C
- hot air pen
- kapton tape
- a large convection oven which goes to maybe ~210°C (doesn't reflow reliably).

Unfortunately the board doesn't make good contact with the hot plate because it warps upwards when heating the backside

Comment: Assuming this is just a prototype, the obvious solution is leaded solder/paste and reduce the temperatures accordingly.

Comment: If you have a 300C hot plate and it's single-sided I would use the hot plate and a thermometer to reflow it.

Comment: @Lundin The connector has already solder charges on its legs with are lead-free, so I am a bit hesitant to use leaded solder even if its a prototype, but I would use it as a last resort. I am worried that mixing the two solder compositions won't lead to reliable reflow for each and every pin (over 200 pins).

Comment: @user1850479 the hot plate does have a thermometer integrated and is pretty good and controlling its temperature. But as I wrote my issue is, that the PCB doesn't make good contact with it because it warps due to the bottom side being much hotter than the top.

Comment: @tobalt 200 pins!? Soldering a 200 pin BGA manually without a reflow oven is simply madness. Also these would need xray inspection and so on. Hire a professional contractor who got all this equipment.

Comment: The integrated thermometer only tells you the temperature inside the heater but you want to know the PCB surface temperature. Put a thermometer in contact with a larger copper plane and monitor the actual surface temperature. Gradually bring the surface up to ~150-200C (or what your paste recommends), then put directly into the hot plate to quickly do the reflow. Might want to practice once on an empty PCB but it's not too tricky once you can see the PCB temperature.

Comment: Don't do it for the BGA. I worked for a company once and was tasked to run tests to see if they could get away with hot air in-house. These rework staff were pros and these were BGAs with less than 200 pins. Every board failed testing.

Comment: I don't think his plastic connector is literally a BGA part, but probably a standard SMD part with pads on the underside.

Comment: @user1850479 Indeed... I linked the datasheet above. After reviewing that and your hot plate method, I feel positive for another manual try with more solder paste to make sure the charges really make good contact with the paste.

Comment: If the pcb warps use clamps to force it down and maybe assist with hot air from the top. Or preheat the board with the oven to minimize warping.

Comment: The only reason why you would specify in exotic Samtec connector like this in a project is because you have high quality concerns and/or few other options. So why are you messing around with it by hand? It's like insisting on buying an expensive Rolls Royce and then send it for repairs at some local mechanic in your home town.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, especially @user1850479 .

I put a glass petri dish above the component to create a kind of hothouse and then set the whole thing on the hotplate.

I set the hotplate to 270 °C after doing some tests with a thermo couple.

The initial buckling prevented full contact so the surface could heat gently to around 150~200 °C. After about half a minute I pressed down on the hothouse, flattening the board against the hotplate. Within about 15 more seconds the area reflowed evenly and nicely.

The result was very beautiful and reliable.

[image]

In this side view one can see that several rows of pins have reflowed to a near identical result. Also, I am sure that indeed all pins' charges have reflowed because the connector drops down a bit when that happens as described in its datasheet linked in the question.

Comment: Glad you got it.  You should mark this as the answer.